# How to properly generalize a definite integral?

Tags: integration, physics

I know, I know.  On the can, this problem seems simple.  Just take $\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm{d}x$ and write is as $\int f(x)\mathrm{d}x$.  However, when I tried to do that on an Engineering Dynamics problem, it didn't work very well.

We have a motorcycle going around a path with an acceleration of $-0.001s\space \mathrm{m/s}$.  The distance of the path happens to be $150\pi$.  The initial speed is 25.  Since we know $a\mathrm{d}s=v\mathrm{d}v$,  That readily lends itself to this integral equation:
$$-\int_0^{150\pi}0.001s\mathrm{d}s=\int_{25}^vv\mathrm{d}s$$  This give the correct answer as provided in the book.  However, I also attempted the following combination to get the ***change*** in $v$:
$$\int_0^s0.001s\mathrm{d}s=\int_0^vv\mathrm{d}s$$which solves to $v=\sqrt{0.001}\times s$.  This renders a likely solution of a change of $14\space\mathrm{m/s}$ in $v$ -the actual change is closer to 5.  This is obviously wrong.
I know why the first integral equation *does* work, but would someone be so kind as to tell me why the second one fails?

What is wrong with assuming $0$ rather than using, say, $v_1$ and $v_2$?

I need to understand my mistake so I don't make it in the future!  Thanks!

Comment: "Since we know that $a\text{ d}s = v\text{ d}s$" Typo here? $a\text{ d}s = v\text{ d}v$ makes more sense.

Comment: $\int a \text{ds} =\int v \text{dv}$, no?

Comment: Fixed.  *9 more to go....*

Answer (score 0):

$$v_1 - v_0 = \int_{v_0}^{v_1} dv = \int_{s_0}^{s_1} \frac{dv}{ds} ds = \int_{s_0}^{s_1} \frac{dv}{dt} \frac{dt}{ds} ds = \int_{s_0}^{s_1} \frac{a}{v} ds$$

Does that answer your question?